# Django give a model a prequel or sequel relation

Tags: python, django, model

So I have a book model with simple title and description

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

How could I set up a model so I can say Book 1 has a sequel named Book 2, and Book 2 will show that Book 1 is a prequel?

So it would look something like:

Book 1 Title
This book is about...
Sequel: Book 2

Book 2 Title
This book is set after Book 1...
Prequel: Book 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a self-relation.

```
class Book(models.Model):
   ...
  sequel = models.OneToOneField('self', null=True, related_name='prequel')
   ...
```

Comment: Hmm I've gotten it to correctly display the sequel but how do I get it to display the prequel? {{Book.sequel}}. {{Book.prequel}}?

Comment: @user1043816: Used the wrong type by accident. It should be better now.